# Coloring specific pixels of a JPanel

Tags: java, swing, jpanel

Say the size of my `JPanel` is 200 x 200. Is the following pseudo code possible?:

```
for(int x=0; x< 200;x++){
for(int y=0;y< 200;y++){
    if(x%2==0 && y%2==0){
         panel.setColor(x-Coord, y-Coord, Color a);
            }else{
          panel.setColor(x-Coord, y-Coord, Color b);
              }
     }
}
```

How can I paint specific pixels  of a `JPanel`? As you can see I used `setColor()` in my pseudo code because I didn't find any predefined method in Java for that. How do I do that?

Comment: Yeah, override `paintComponent()` of `JPanel` method instead

Comment: What is the purpose for wanting to set the color of specific pixels? There are various ways to achieve that, some better suited to one purpose than another.

Comment: @Arvind Do you have any example how to do it? So how does paintComponent() paint pixels gradually?

Comment: @Berger but I dont want to change the colors of an image but of a JPanel

Comment: @JohnDoe  : in the linked answer, the generated image is drawn on the `Graphics` of the `JPanel` . At least if your panel won't change size, it will be far more efficient to precompute the image, and just paint it in `paintComponent`, instead of recomputing the whole thing on each repaint .

Comment: @Berger Ah okay that helped! Thanks :)